# How can I migrate all my font customizations in Eclipse from one computer to another?

Tags: eclipse

So I just bought a new computer.  My last computer was the first computer I had when I started using Eclipse exclusively as my IDE.  So I assumed just copying over C:\eclipse\ from one computer to the other would work.  It did for everything except for the font stuff.  I changed Courier New to Consolas and also a few color changes from the default PDT stuff.

Where are these modifications on my old computer? I want to get them integrated on the new computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are saved in the workspace directory. JDT uses separate prefs file.

Comment: I'm on the new computer, don't wanna plug in the new one until tomorrow -- do you know the path(s) of the files I'll need to grab?  Is it just everything in {workspace_path}/.metadata/?  I'd imagine since the paths are slightly different there could be an issue

Comment: The `./metadata` is structured, every plugin has its own directory and files. For example specifically for text font in Java editor I found an entry here: `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs`. I guess jsut copying the `./metadata` is the easiest you can do, but you would probably need all the plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Export the preferences from your old Eclipse, and import them in your new Eclipse.

This gets rid of the "what is stored where" problem.

Comment: Is there an "export everything" button?

Comment: @Andrew, that is the default action of export preferences.